How to determine the treatment time for untreated in difference-in-differences design
I'm estimating the effect of treatment initiation on health outcomes using a Difference-in-Differences (DiD) design. The timeline is defined relative to the treatment date, not calendar time. For the treated group, the index time (t=0) is the date when each individual initiated treatment, with a pre-period of up to 3 years before and a post-period of up to 3 years after treatment.
My challenge is determining the pseudo-treatment date for the control group (those who did not initiate treatment) to similarly define their pre- and post-periods.
I am considering randomly assigning pseudo-treatment dates to the controls based on the distribution of treatment initiation dates among the treated group. Specifically, I plan to stratify the participants based on key variables, and within each stratum, sample with replacement from duration between diagnosis and treatment initiation observed in the treated group to assign a pseudo-treatment date for the controls in that stratum.
My questions are:

Is there a better approach to assigning pseudo-treatment dates?
If this approach is valid, how can I calculate the uncertainty due to the randomness of the pseudo-treatment dates for controls? Would conducting a sensitivity analysis by varying these dates be sufficient?
Are there any references or studies that discuss this method or a similar problem? I'm struggling with terminology and would appreciate guidance on what to look for.

Thank you!

Why not define the untreated individuals as “always 0”?

This is the model I'm considering: (β0 + β1 X + β2 period + β3 X*period) I am defining them as untreated the entire time yes (so X = 0 always for untreated individuals), but my struggle is with the period term (0 before treatment for both groups and 1 after treatment for both), does that make sense? I might be missing or misunderstanding something.

It depends. Do individuals start treatment at different times?

Yes, they all start treatment at different times, which is why my time scale isn't calendar time, but it is time since treatment (also, the duration between diagnosis and treatment initiation is different for individuals). My index date (t = 0 is the treatment, the actual date is different for each individual) and my pre-period would be t= -0.5, - 1,..,-3 and my post-period would be t = 0.5,1,..,3 that is why I want to come up with pseudo treatment dates for the untreated. I hope that clarifies things; please let me know if it doesn't.

Right now, what I'm considering is either Approach 1: random assignment based on the distribution of duration between treatment and diagnosis in the treated group (what I described above) or Approach 2: Match on propensity score and assign the same treatment initiation date to the matched control
